# Manually need to synchronize access to synchronized list/map/set etc

Tags: java

Collection class provides various methods to get thread safe collections . Then why is it necessary to manually synchronize access while iterating ?

Comment: Why do you think?  What confuses you about it?

Comment: Because that is how the authors wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each method is thread safe.  If you make multiple calls to a synchronized collection this is not thread safe unless you hold a lock explicitly.  Using an Iterator involves making multiple calls to the iterator implicitly so there is no way around this.

What some of the Concurrency Libraries collections do is provide weak consistency.  They provide a pragmatic solution which is that an added or removed element may, or may not be seen when Iterating.

---

A simple example of a thread safe collection used in an unsafe manner.

```
private final List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(
                                              new ArrayList<String>());

list.add("hello");
String hi = list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

Both add and remove are thread safe and you won't get an error using them individually.  The problem is another thread can alter the collection BETWEEN calls (not within calls) causing this code to break in a number of ways.

Comment: "If you make multiple calls to a synchronized collection this is not thread safe" ,then why does java say that it is synchronized..?

Comment: Each individual operation is synchronized, but multiple operations in sequence won't be synchronized as a group unless you do so explicitly.

Comment: The class and all its method are thread safe, but that doesn't prohibit you from using them in an unsafe manner in combination.